# Add User Role: Pre-saved in User-Meta [SOLVED]

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, users, user-roles

I am adding an action after user registration to add another user role based off the users meta_value.
When I use:

```
add_action('um_after_save_registration_details', 'custom_after_new_user_register', 10, 2);

function custom_after_new_user_register($user_id) {

$user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);
if (!in_array('subscriber', $user->roles)) {
    $user->add_role(editor);
    
  }}
```

It successfully adds the role 'editor', however, I seem to fail to extract the saved user_meta and make it work dynamically.

Below is what I got to but it's not working

```
add_action('um_after_save_registration_details', 'custom_after_new_user_register', 10, 2);

function custom_after_new_user_register($user_id) {

$user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);
$get_portal_number = get_user_meta($user_id, 'portal_number', false);
if (!in_array('subscriber', $user->roles)) {
    $user->add_role($get_portal_number);
    
  }}
```

SOLVED:

```
$get_portal_number = get_user_meta($user_id, 'meta_key', false);
```

will return an array and value needs to be a single value, hence it must be set to

```
$get_portal_number = get_user_meta($user_id, 'meta_key', true);
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
$get_portal_number = get_user_meta($user_id, 'meta_key', false)[0];
```

if you need to set false in a different case.

Thanks to [NightHawk](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/14656/nighthawk) for solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're not passing an actual ID to `get_user_meta`, but merely a string of `id`:

```php
$get_portal_number = get_user_meta('id', 'portal_number', false);
```

In addition, the third parameter is set to `false`, which will return an array. You're passing that value straight to `$user->add_role`, but that expects a string.

You either have to loop over your post meta results, or return the role as a single value by passing `true` as the third parameter.

Try this:

```php
add_action('um_after_save_registration_details', 'custom_after_new_user_register', 10, 2);

function custom_after_new_user_register($user_id) {

$user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);
$get_portal_number = get_user_meta($user_id, 'portal_number', true);
if (!in_array('subscriber', $user->roles)) {
    $user->add_role($get_portal_number);
    
  }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think you pointed out one error, I have just updated the question to reflect your answer but unfortunately, that did not resolve it, perhaps there is something I need to include to the file such as global$wpdb or other?

Comment: So we know the hook `um_after_save_registration_details` is good, and that you're getting the correct `$user_id`, because you were able to set the editor role. Does this role exist in WordPress that you're trying to assign?

Comment: Yes, it is already existing

Comment: Next I would try to see what `get_user_meta` actually returns... whether the value comes up or whether it returns false.

Comment: With get_user_meta, returns an Array, only print_r will actually "print", echo and return will just print a number

Comment: As an aside, `get_user_meta($user_id, 'portal_number', false);` would return an array, whereas `get_user_meta($user_id, 'portal_number', true);` will return a single value. Role needs to be a single value, not an array.

Comment: I didn't notice you changed false to true too! I just tested it works as you written, sorry for the hassle and Thanks a lot!!